# Silverlight: Should I be using IDataErrorInfo, INotifyDataErrorInfo, or both?

Tags: silverlight

Should I be using IDataErrorInfo, INotifyDataErrorInfo, or both?

If I use both, should I offer the same error in both or should I only offer sync errors from IDataErrorInfo and only async errors from INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're working only in Silverlight, you should implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  From the documentation:

> In general, new entity classes for Silverlight should implement INotifyDataErrorInfo for the added flexibility instead of implementing IDataErrorInfo.

However, if you want to share code with WPF, `IDataErrorInfo` is supported in both Silverlight and WPF.

Comment: INotifyDataErrorInfo is in .NET 4.5, and therefore available to WPF, as well.  Should one ever implement both on the same class at the same time?

Comment: @ScottStafford You really don't need both, if you're using 4.5 - you can use either mechanism you prefer in WPF 4.5 (This answer predated 4.5 by a long time...)